# TCP replication of topics

Tags: chronicle

According to the documentation here: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Engine one is able to do pub/sub using maps. This allows one to create a construct similar to topics that are available in middleware such as Tibco, 29W, Kafka and use that as a way of sending events across processes. Is this a recommended usage of chronicle map? What kind of latency can I expect if both publisher and subscriber stay in the same machine?
My second question is, how can this be extended to send messages across machines? How does this work with enterprise TCP replication?

My requirement is to create thousands of topics and use them to communicate across processes running in different machines (in a LAN). Each of these topics would be written by a single source and read by multiple readers running in same or different machines. If the source of a particular topic dies, that source's replica would start writing to the topic and listeners will continue to receive messages. These messages need not be stored for replay.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a recommended usage of chronicle map?

Yes, you can use engine to support event notification across a machine.  However, if you want lowest latencies you might need to send a notification via Queue and keep the latest value in a map.

> What kind of latency can I expect if both publisher and subscriber stay in the same machine?

It depends on your use case esp the size of the data (in maps case the number of entries as well)  The Latency for Map in Engine is around 30 - 100 us, however the latency for Queue is around 2 - 5 us.

> My second question is, how can this be extended to send messages across machines?

For this you need our licensed product but the code is the same.

> Each of these topics would be written by a single source and read by multiple readers running in same or different machines. If the source of a particular topic dies, that source's replica would start writing to the topic and listeners will continue to receive messages.

Most likely, the simplest solution is to have a Map where each topic is a different key.  This will send the latest value for that topic to the consumers.
If you need to recorded every event, a Queue is likely to be a better choice. If you don't need to retain the data for long, you can use a very sort file rotation.